# Construction of positive recurrent Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ be i.i.d. with values in $\mathbb N_0$. Define a Markov chain via the following transition matrix:

$$p(0,n) = \mathbb P(X_1 = n-1) \qquad p(m,n) = \mathbb P\left(\sum_{k=1}^m X_k = n\right)$$

**Under what conditions is this Markov chain positive recurrent?**

I tried to find conditions under which the chain is irreducible and has an invariant distribution, but couldn't pin down the calculation. It would then follow that it is positive recurrent.

Comment: What kind of conditions are you looking for?

Comment: I think the only way to have an influence on the problem is via the distribution of $X_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Markov chain is the total population of a branching process with offspring distribution $X$, 
except that when the population goes extinct (hits state 0) it regenerates a random number of 
ancestors who again start to grow family trees. Standard results on the extinction of 
branching processes gets you pretty far.

Let's assume that $\mathbb{P}(X=0)>0$, $\mathbb{P}(X=1)>0$, and $\mathbb{P}(X>1)>0$ so that the chain 
is irreducible on the state space $\mathbb N_0$.

When $\mathbb{E}(X)<1$, then the expected time to extinction starting with one individual 
 is finite; $\mathbb{E}_1(T_0)<\infty$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}_0(T_0)&=&1+\sum p(0,n)\,\mathbb{E}_n(T_0)\\[5pt]
                 &\leq&1+\sum p(0,n)\, n \,\mathbb{E}_1(T_0)\\[5pt]
                 &=&1+(\mathbb{E}(X)+1)\, \mathbb{E}_1(T_0)<\infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore the state 0 is positive recurrent and hence the whole chain.

If $\mathbb{E}(X)>1$, the chain is transient. The population will grow to $\infty$ 
with probability one.

If $\mathbb{E}(X)=1$, extinction is guaranteed so the chain is recurrent.
When $\mathbb{E}(X^2)<\infty$ the chain is  null since $\mathbb{E}_1(T_0)=\infty$. 
I'm not sure about the case  $\mathbb{E}(X)=1$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\infty$.

---

**Footnote 1:** Where does the equation come from?

Let's start with some boundary theory for Markov chains.

Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain
 with state space $\cal S$ and let $B\subset {\cal S}$. Define
$$V_B=\inf(n\geq 0: X_n\in B),\qquad T_B=\inf(n\geq 1: X_n\in B),$$
and 
$$h(x)=\mathbb{E}_x(V_B),\qquad f(x)=\mathbb{E}_x(T_B).$$
Notice that $h(x)=f(x)$ for $x\notin B$. Using the shift operator 
we  write $T_B=1+V_B\circ\theta_1$ so 
$$f(x)=\mathbb{E}_x(1+V_B\circ\theta_1)=1+\mathbb{E}_x(h(X_1)).$$

In your problem (with $B=\{0\}$), since there are no transitions 
from $0$ to itself, we get $$\mathbb{P}_0(f(X_1)=h(X_1))=1,$$ and hence
$$f(0)=\mathbb{E}_0(T_0)=1 +\mathbb{E}_0(f(X_1))=1 +\sum_n p(0,n)\,\mathbb{E}_n(T_0).$$

Comment: Thanks! Where does the $1$ come from in these equations and why is $\mathbb E_n(T_0)\leq n\mathbb E_1(T_0)$, how general is that inequality?

Comment: @madison54 I've added a footnote to explain the equation better. Perhaps later I will add another to explain the inequality.